# Валидация и проверка файла htaccess на ошибки

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как провести валидацию на ошибки файла htaccess.

Файлы бывают разных размеров и ошибка в одной строчке может привести к поломке всего сервера.

Может есть онлайн инструменты по валидации файлов(я не говорб про конструкторы htaccess) ?

Может есть ручные способы проверок?

Answer (score 1):

> apache2ctl configtest

Comment: Спасобо, посмотрю

Comment: Кстати, скорее всего этой команде нужно будет повышение прав